# Push WindowsFormsHost element into the back

Tags: wpf

My wpf app has a "Open PDF" feature and I'm using `PdfViewer` from the **PdfPrintingNet** & **PdfViewerNet** libraries. My issue is that since my app can be windowed and resized the PDF viewer gets drawn in front of my scrollbars thus rendering the use of them moot and the layout looks awry. Is there a way where I can put my PDF window to the back and not drawn over my scrollbars?

Here is how I have my PDF view:

```
           <!-- winforms host with embedded PDFPrint.net viewer -->
            <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="_pdfViewerHost" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}">
                <pdfview:PdfViewer IsCalledFromWPF="True" />
            </WindowsFormsHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused due to how the `WindowsFormsHost` is rendered.

They call it the "airspace" problem.

It's always drawn on top of everything else, and there is no way you can change it unfortunately.

I would recommend finding a native WPF PDF viewer control.